# Kernel Panic on fresh install of 13.04

Tags: kernel

I went back to Ubuntu last night and gave my laptop a fresh install of 13.04 after alot of talk about how stable and quick it had become. It looks awesome!

It worked great for 18 hours, but now I get Kernel Panic. Three of them in the last 30 min.

I tried to remove the Ubuntu One Music Lens via the USC. It seemed to work, but before I could log in and out again, the system crashed.

When I booted up again, the silly music search function was still there in the dash. I tried to reboot, but it was still there.

I went for the Software Center again to search for Ubuntu One Music, and the system crashed again.

I got back in to try to install Ubuntu One Music again, but it was never removed.

I have been able to open Firefox and write this post.. don't know if it will crash again and why it does that.

Any idea why the Kernel Panics occure and what I need to do..?

Thanks alot and hope it is an easy fix!

Comment: UPDATE: Tried to setup Thunderbird, typed in existing email address and password and pressed enter. Straight into another crash.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: `ubuntu-bug linux` in a terminal will fire up the bug reporting tool for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the kernel panics occured is to be found here:

[[raring] BCM4313 -- bcmwl triggers panics with 3.7 and 3.8 kernels](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1098225)

The kernel panic problem got fixed by installing the firmware-b43-installer.